# How to control UITableView editing using swipe iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swipe

Am working in an iPhone app using `UITableView`. I have added the editing option in an `UIViewController` subview UITableView. When the user `swipe the screen the Delete button is showing` in this scenario i have changed the barbutton items **'Edit' to 'Done'**. In this case i have tracked the control from below delegates,

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when the user again swipe the view the **"Delete"** button is hiding but i can't trigger the control. So that i can't change the barbutton item **"Done" to "Edit"**. Could you please help me to solve this problem? Where i can trigger the swipe control to hide the 'Delete' options? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // update button title here
}
```